# Comparing the values of 2 combo-boxes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have two combo box, one with a start date, and the other is ending date.
I want to do `if(combobox1 > combobox2)` check if the start date is greater than the ending date MessageBox.Show("You have chosen a great starting date of the final");

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just access both values of your ComboBoxes and then you can use DateTime.Compare method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Dates are old and were taken from a database structured in year / month / day

Comment: Then you can use DateTime.ParseExact to format it how you want

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this :

```
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.toString());
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(ComboBox2.SelectedValue.toString());
if(d1 > d2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some message");
}
```

Comment: CS1061  C# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you help me ?

Comment: Add `using System.String` on top of your class file @B.Pizhev

Answer (score 0):

This might fix the issue

```
var StartDate = comboBoxDate1.Text;
var EndDate = comboBoxDate2.Text;
var eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
var sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
if(StartDate != "" && StartDate != "" && sDate > eDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please ensure that the End Date is greater than the Start Date.");
}
```

Comment: Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type 'Date' and 'Date' ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you have under your ComboBoxes.

If you have just texts:

```
var dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(ComboBox1.Text);
var dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(ComboBox2.Text);


if(dateFrom > dateTo)
{
   // your code
}
```

If you have bound objects where `ValueMember` is of Type `DateTime`

```
var dateFrom = (DateTime)ComboBox1.SelectedValue;
var dateTo = (DateTime)ComboBox2.SelectedValue;


if(dateFrom > dateTo)
{
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBox1.Text);
DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBox2.Text);
if(date1>date2)
{
MessageBox.Show("You have chosen a great starting date of the final");
}
```